# Unable to set the Primary color to the Toolbar in Android Material Design

Tags: android, material-design

I just started working with Material Design.I am facing issue in setting primary color to Toolbar and fitting the width of tool bar to screensize. Here is my Code

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<include
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    layout="@layout/app_bar" />

<TextView
    android:layout_below="@id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

app_bar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
```

styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme -->
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
<!-- Application theme for < v22-->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_color</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_colordark</item>
</style>
```

styles-v22.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Application theme For v22 -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary_color</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_colordark</item>
</style>
```

colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><resources>
<color name="primary_color">#FFC107</color>
<color name="primary_colordark">#FFA000</color>
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

}
```

output:
[image]
The emulator is 5.1 version. The min sdk is 4.0  for the project.
When i tried setting some color to the toolbar background , i see the Toolbar not fitting to screenwidth and primary color didn't got applied. Tried keeping Toolbar in LinearLayout but invain.

Kindly help me in resolving this.

I am hardly seeing any examples with material design. If anyone is familiar with some links kindly provide  it.(Seen Androidhive and in youtube slidenr).

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try *app_bar.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?
   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@color/primary_color">
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked . But Still i dont see my Toolbar fully stretched to the screen. There are spaces on top, left and Right.Not sure any issue with height width. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Remove padding activity_main -> RelativeLayout (root)

Comment: Sorry , i dont know how it got added. Problem Resolved. Thank you,